# bash- syntax error: operand expected- occurs after creating temp file

Tags: bash, stdin, cat

So I am trying to loop through columns in a file to find the average and median...  The loop works fine, but when I add a temp file (for when using stdin to specify the file), it gives the error:

`((: i<: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<")`

This is the for loop:
`for (( i=$colIndex;i<$numCols;i++ ))`

Creating the temp file: 
`cat - > temp`

EDIT:

The full stdin code:

```
if [[ $# -eq 2 ]]
  then
      fileName=$2
  #file name was not given
  elif [[ $# -eq 1 ]]
  then
      #file name comes from the user
      fileName=/dev/stdin
      cat - > temp
  #incorrect number of arguments
  else
      echo "Usage: stats {-rows|-cols} [file]"
      exit 1
  fi
```

Code to get number of columns ($numCols):

```
#get number of columns
     while read -a cols
     do
         numCols=0
         for i in "${cols[@]}"
         do
             numCols=`expr $numCols + 1`
         done
         #only need one row
         break
     done < "${2:-/dev/stdin}"
```

Any help would be great, Thanks!

Comment: Show the script with those lines in context relative to one another?

Comment: They arent really relative to one another though.  Without the `cat - > temp` code, the error goes away, with it, the error comes back.

Comment: for ((i=1;i<;i++)); do echo yes;done
    bash: ((: i<: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<") 
$numCols is null.

Answer (score 1):

numCols is not set (or not set to a number):

```
$ colIndex=1
$ numCols=""
$ for (( i=$colIndex;i<$numCols;i++ )); do echo $i; done
-bash: ((: i<: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "<")
```

UPDATE: I think the reason this is happening is that `cat - > temp` empties stdin into the temp file. Then when you do `while read ... done < "${2:-/dev/stdin}"` there's nothing left in stdin, so the loop never runs, and `numCols` never gets assigned.

There are several problems here: when you copy stdin to a temp file, you need to then set `fileName` to the temp file's path, and then have the loop read from `$fileName` instead of (maybe) stdin. Also, you should be using `mktemp` instead of a fixed (and pathless) temp file name. Also, looping over the elements of an array to count them is unnecessarily complex; just use `numCols=${#cols[@]}`.

Finally, having a loop you'll always break out of on the first iteration... that isn't really a loop at all. And it's not only pointless, it's actually problematic because if the file is empty the loop never runs and `numCols` never gets set.

How about something like this:

```
...
elif [[ $# -eq 1 ]]
then
    #no filename given, reading from stdin
    fileName="$(mktemp -t "$(basename "$0")")" || {
        echo "Error creating temp file" >&2
        exit 1
    }
    cat - > "$fileName"
else

...
read -a cols <"$fileName" # Just read the first line (or null if the file is empty)
numCols=${#cols[@]}
if [ $numCols = 0 ]; then
    echo "This file doesn't seem to have any columns (at least judging by the first line)" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but why would me adding `cat - > temp` cause the code that gets the number of columns to be skipped and ultimately cause that error?

Comment: Well I got it to work... I changed the 1st line from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`    I know there are some differences between the two, but what are the differences that made this all to work?